# Connection retry in NSURLSession

Tags: connection, swift2, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration, resque-retry

I want to implement the connection retry in NSURLSession. Is there any parameter we need to set to achieve this like '*timeoutIntervalForRequest*' and NSURLSession takes the responsibility to retry the connection.

If there is no any parameter for this, how can we achieve this?

My current code is as follows:

```
func isHostConnected(jsonString:NSDictionary) -> NSDictionary
{
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://***.*.*.**:****/")!)

    do {
        request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonString, options: [])
    } catch {
        //error = error1
        request.HTTPBody = nil
    }
    request.timeoutInterval = 4.0 //(number as! NSTimeInterval)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("gzip", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-encoding")

    var JSONdata: AnyObject = ["" : ""] as Dictionary<String, String>
    print(JSONdata)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    var responseCode = -1

    let group = dispatch_group_create()
    dispatch_group_enter(group)

    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            responseCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            let JSONresdata: AnyObject = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers))
            JSONdata = JSONresdata as! NSDictionary
        }
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }).resume()

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    print("responseCode == 200: \(responseCode)")
    return (JSONdata) as! NSDictionary
}
```

When response code is not 200 then this function should retry the connection again. Can I do the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check the answer of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478272/how-to-retry-a-block-based-url-request)

```
 func someMethodWithRetryCounter(retryCounter: Int) {
     if retryCounter == 0 {
    return
 }

 retryCounter--
 var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest.requestWithURL(NSURL.URLWithString(self.baseUrl.stringByAppendingString(path)))

 (self) weakSelf = self
 var dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data: NSData, response: NSURLResponse, error: NSErrorPointer) in        var httpResponse: NSHTTPURLResponse = response
    var responseStatusCode: UInt = httpResponse.statusCode()
    if responseStatusCode != 200 {
        weakSelf.someMethodWithRetryCounter(retryCounter)
    }
    else {
        completionBlock(results["result"][symbol])
    }

})
dataTask.resume()
}
```

You can also use the following default iOS function. It provide a replacement request body stream if the task needs to resend a request that has a body stream because of an authentication challenge or other recoverable server error.

Check these [Link](https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-part-3-upload-3a5be9a69950)/[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate/URLSession:task:needNewBodyStream:) for reference

```
func URLSession(_ session: NSURLSession,
                task task: NSURLSessionTask,
   needNewBodyStream completionHandler: (NSInputStream?) -> Void)
```

Hope this might be helpful.